# SQL PHP Multiple Queries with PHP-MyAdmin

Tags: php, mysql

I ran into a problem with performing multiple queries in my DB. Each time I query the DB with just a single line of SQL, it stores that data in the DB just fine. But when I try to execute a multi-line query, it becomes a problem. I tried using mysqli_multi_query as well, but still no luck. And I even tried to make the SQL statement into one string, and that also didn't work. I've posted my code below, and any help would be greatly appreciated.

P.S. This is a SPA (Single Paged App) so I cant really do the usual "echo this error out" if I'm getting thrown a error. Instead I'm just having it print the error to a file

### Connection.php

```
    <?php

   //File used for connecting to a database

   //Location of the DB
   $dbhost = 'localhost';
   //User name of the DB
   $dbuser = 'root';
   //Password of the DB
   $dbpass ='';
   //Name of the DB
   $db = 'structures';
    // Connection to the database SERVER. Parameters include: Host, User, and Password
   $conn = mysqli_connect($dbhost,$dbuser,$dbpass,$db);
?>
```

### Go2.php

```
<?php

include 'connection.php';

$firstName = $_POST["firstName"];
$middleName = $_POST["middleName"];
$lastName = $_POST["lastName"];
$NetIDQuest = $_POST["NetIDQuest"];
$NetID = $_POST["NetID"];
$InstQuest = $_POST["InstQuest"];
$Entity = $_POST["Entity"];
$Consulting = $_POST["Consulting"];
$Reimbursed = $_POST["Reimbursed"];
$Royalties = $_POST["Royalties"];
$Equity = $_POST["Equity"];
$PublicQuest = $_POST["PublicQuest"];
$PublicVal = $_POST["PublicVal"];
$SignConfirm = $_POST["SignConfirm"];

$sql = "INSERT INTO user_info(NetID) SELECT NetID from user where NetID = '$NetID';";    // Insert the FK of NetID into the user_signature table before update

$sql. =  "UPDATE user_info SET FirstName = '$firstName', MiddleName = '$middleName', LastName = '$lastName' WHERE NetID = '$NetID';"; //Update the User_Info Table
mysqli_multi_query($conn,$sql) or die (mysql_error());

/*
$sql = "INSERT INTO user_signature(NetID) SELECT NetID from user_info where NetID = '$NetID';";  // Insert the FK of NetID into the user_signature table before update
mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error());

$sql = "UPDATE user_signature SET Signature = '$SignConfirm' WHERE NetID = '$NetID';"; // Update the user_signature table
mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error());

$sql = "INSERT INTO financial(NetID) SELECT NetID from user_info where NetID = '$NetID';";  
mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error());
*/

$myfile = fopen("newfile.txt", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
$txt = mysqli_error($conn);
fwrite($myfile, $txt);
fclose($myfile);


?>
```

Comment: You can only pass multiple different queries using `mysqli_multi_query`; anything else will fail. Can you add the code where you've tried to use that, and explain how it didn't work?

Comment: @JustinE.Samuels - the first thing I see is that you're using `mysql_error` if the query fails. You can't mix `mysql_` and `mysqli_` functions like that - if you're using `mysqli_multi_query`, use `mysqli_error($conn)` instead

Comment: also, please stop using `mysql_` altogether.  It is deprecated  You are on the right track, but not quite there yet.

Comment: You could do those 2 queries in 1 - `INSERT INTO user_info(NetID, FirstName, MiddleName, LastName) SELECT NetID, '$firstName', '$middleName', '$lastName' FROM user WHERE NetID = '$NetID'`. Although since you are using `mysqli` you should start using prepared statements/parameters to prevent sql injection

Comment: instead of inserting the FK , you can configure the database to cascade on update unless you don't want it to always cascade.  
for production a framework would be a lot easier

Comment: you say `I cant really do the usual "echo this error out" if I'm getting thrown a error`, but you have `or die (mysql_error())` in `mysqli_multi_query($conn,$sql) or die (mysql_error());`?

Comment: @niceman I have it already set to Cascade on update and do nothing on Delete. But I was doing that so I can place that specific data at a certain spot in the DB

Comment: @andrewsi I've updated it above again, still no luck. This time I've tried to print the error in the file

Comment: @Sean : I just do that as a creature of habit. I know it's not going to do nothing, so that's why I tried to print it to a file

Comment: Just thought I'd mention that you should always sanitize your data before sending it to MySQL.

Comment: hmmmmm , why inserting a data from a table to a table when you could just make a FK ?

Comment: I feel like a fish out of water with SQL. I usually dont mess with it that much, so all yalls comments is GREATLY appreciated. I usually stick on the front-end, but trying to get better on the back

Comment: ok Justin, what's the error you see in the file ? I mean what's not working ?

Comment: notes from the manual - `how to catch errors` - http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php#106126 :: `leave the last semi-colon out` - http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php#115325

Comment: @nicema, I dont have to insert then ? I know for a FACT the FK is set, since when I go to insert into the DB from the admin panel, I only get the NetID options which are already in the DB. So if I want to update the user_info table with new data, I dont have to INSERT the FK first ?

Comment: yes , you don't have to do that , linking the tables with the FK is all what you need unless there is a new Netid that's not in the database at all

Comment: @niceman, the file is not giving me a error at all.

Comment: So what's the problem ?!!!

Comment: @niceman : Yea, thats why I was Inserting. Because users hit a log-in screen first, then enter their NetID into the DB. If they're NEtID is not in the DB, it adds it in

Comment: @niceman: I have no clue, the DB is just not inserting the data I'm passing it from the form

Comment: forgive me @niceman, it was a simple typo that got me. I apologize